# Creating marker index in BBEdit

Tags: indexing, marker, bbedit

In building Wordpress sites for customers I need to create a marker index for their theme stylesheet. BBEdit's Make Marker command uses grep regular expressions to find and "Mark As" to build an index for a document.
The stylesheets for a particular theme are well commented by the vendor:
1. /* (Category Name text)
2. -------------------------------****/

I need to find all the comments, that is lines beginning with /****, 
and return into the BBEdit "Mark As" field the line containing the category name text.

Anybody?
:)

Answer (score 1):

After some poking around, I found the answer to this.
The index entries are found using this

```
^/\* .*$
```

and "mark as" is simply

```
&
```